# How to pass default $counter into all the different for loop in PHP?

Tags: variables, loops

I have a design like:

```
-------------------------------
|          |                  |
|    2     |                  |
|          |                  |
------------         1        |
|          |                  |
|    3     |                  |
|          |                  |
-------------------------------
```

But the programmer/designer placed the `<div>`s like:

```
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="1">1</div>
```

With proper CSS they're aligned as the visual one. Now he's making a loop to echo data from database. If I don't want to change the HTML hierarchy, the the loop's hierarchy's:

```php
<div id="2"><?php
  for( condition ) {
      execute News 2 here
  } ?></div>
<div id="3"><?php
  for( condition ) {
     execute News 3 here
  } ?></div>
<div id="2"><?php
  for( condition ) {
     execute News 1 here
  } ?></div>
```

But the **REAL PROBLEM** is:
As the `$counter` is incrementing, the value declared first (zero) is incrementing loop by loop the default value is incrementing. So, in the first loop the `$counter=0`, incremented to 1; in the second loop the `$counter=1`, incremented to 2; so in the third loop the $counter=2, incremented to 3. But we want the $counter incrementing 2, 3, 1 respectively.

So the **REAL QUESTION** is:

- **HOW TO FETCH THE DEFAULT $counter VALUE WITHOUT INCREMENT, BEING DECLARED AFTER SOME PRECEDING LOOPS?**

I know it's a childish question. But I'm stuck here. Can it be done declaring `global`?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values (i.e. 2,3,1; which are a arbitrary ordering of values) into an (global) array, and just set the actual "counter" to the value in the array.

```
$values = array(2, 3, 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < x; $i++) {
    $div = $values[$i];
    do_something_with_div($div);
}
```